# Device Compatibility of my app

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I created an Android application, but I cannot view it on play store and when I access it from web play store I found that:

> Cette application n'est pas compatible avec votre appareil.

I don't know the reason of that 
here is my build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'

    compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commande.soqop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

I have tested on Samsung Tab 4 (Android 5.0)  and Samsung S5 (Android 6)
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `targetSdkVersion` of your app. The devices on which you tested might be above the version you mentioned in `build.gradle`.

Replace target SDK with the latest one :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commande.soqop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

Comment: but if I increase it to the last one all devices below the sdk will not work ?

Comment: We already set the minimum sdk to 15. So all the devices above api level 15 will be supported

Answer (score 0):

It will almost certainly be something in your manifest settings. Can you edit your question to show your AndroidManifest.xml?